# Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 vs 1.2.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm new to Jquery Mobile and I want to build a web app using it but which version is best to use and why? is it the latest 1.3.1 or 1.2.1? Need some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 1.3.1 mainly because it has bigger set of UI widgets.

From the stability point they are equally stable. Errors found in version 1.2 and 1.2.1 are also fixed in 1.3.1.

Also 1.3.1 allows you to use a higher range of jQuery versions (up to jQuery 2.0). 1.2 and 1.2.1. are locked to max. jQuery 1.8.3. jQM 1.3.1 also has a better handling of page transitions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll use 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

**Go for the latest version which gives you more functions and features.**

Check their website to see 1.3.1 has lot more features to offer than the earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to use the latest js files for any plugin from the stability, efficiency, improvements and enhancements point of view.

I will suggest to use the latest **Jquery Mobile 1.3.1** version.